# How to get the path of a remote server folder using PHP code?

Tags: php

I am facing a problem related to remote servers.

I want to get the path of a folder which is present in another server using PHP code. So can anyone please help me out how I will get that path in my server???

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

File paths are something available to users and their processes running on the server.

You can access whatever items they make available to you through the public internet in a variety of ways, but the filesystem isn't one of those things.

Of course, with that said, there are various server daemon's (httpd's, nfs, ftp, etc) that can make files available, but there is an intermediary process and protocol in between you and the path.

PHP supports a variety of "wrappers" that allow you to use these protocols semi-transparently with many filesystem related functions.  See:  http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php for the details.

I'm not sure why you would want or need a filesystem path.  Perhaps if you explained more fully what you are trying to do and why, you might be able to find a way to accomplish what you want.